# How to use the built-in AlertDialog_listItemLayout

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm showing an AlertDialog using the same built-in `android.R.layout.select_dialog_item` which Android uses to display the `AlertDialog`:

```
    void showCustomAlertDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose any item");

        final List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        items.add("Red");
        items.add("Green");
        items.add("Blue");

        final TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(null,
                R.styleable.AlertDialog, R.attr.alertDialogStyle, 0);

        final int listItemLayoutId = a.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.AlertDialog_listItemLayout,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                listItemLayoutId, items);

        builder.setAdapter(dataAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

The code is similar to what I see in the source code: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.java#L229

I'm also displaying another AlertDialog but using `setItems()`:

```
    void showStandardAlertDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose any item");

        final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

The two displayed dialogs have items displayed in a slightly different way, the padding is different:

[image]

Why is it different, where does the difference come from?

How can I display an AlertDialog with a custom item layout but which looks exactly the same as when using setItems`, no matter current theme?

To give you some background info: What I'm actually trying to do is to show an `AlertDialog` which shows items similar to how it looks with `setItems()`, but show currently selected item set by `dialog.getListView().setSelection(somePos)`. For this, I need an item layout which has background set to `android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator`.
But first, I need to figure out how to get the exact look which the `setItems` uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in the theme passed in the `Context` of the adapter you create and the adapter that is created internally when using `setItems`.

You have to pass a context that uses the default dialog theme, rather than `this` (which uses the Activity theme). You can get that context from the `AlertDialog.Builder`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(builder.getContext(),
                listItemLayoutId, items);
```

[`AlertDialog.Builder#getContext()` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder#getContext()) say:

> Returns a Context with the appropriate theme for dialogs created by this Builder. Applications should use this Context for obtaining LayoutInflaters for inflating views that will be used in the resulting dialogs, as it will cause views to be inflated with the correct theme.

But they should have mentioned that in the documentation for `setAdapter()`.

Comment: Arghh! The context! Thank you very much!

Comment: Wait, it doesn't make sense to me. I am passing `this` as context to `new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` so why isn't `builder.getContext()` actually `this` !?

Comment: Because they use a `ContextThemeWrapper` when you call `AlertDialog.Builder(this)` and the dialog will use that wrapped context. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/AlertDialog.java#468 Thankfully they also return the same wrapped context from `builder.getContext()`